# Snowflake JSON import into Stage with double quote in column value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've set stage file format as JSON and trying to import below data from Azure blob, getting error. see 2nd line last SQLTableName value has double quote.

{"SQLDatabaseName":"TV","SQLSchemaName":"sec","SQLTableName":"UserProfile"}
{"SQLDatabaseName":"LW","SQLSchemaName":"sec","SQLTableName":"User"Profile"}

in sql server i am exporting each row in json above format to move data into snowflake.

Answer (score 2):

Your data in JSON format is incorrect, the second line is not JSON validated.
Check your sample data on this page: [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com)

You should use some escape character when exporting.

It does not validate:

```sql
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"SQLDatabaseName":"LW","SQLSchemaName":"sec","SQLTableName":"User"Profile"}');
```

If you change your data and add an escape character, it will validate:

```sql
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"SQLDatabaseName":"LW","SQLSchemaName":"sec","SQLTableName":"User\'Profile"}');

SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"SQLDatabaseName":"LW","SQLSchemaName":"sec","SQLTableName":"User\\"Profile"}');
```